# Changes in Vue life cycle for Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, migration, vuejs3

I am migrating Vue2 to Vue3. For this, I want to start the changes that Vue2 can handle. So here are the changes in Vue3 lifecycle:

[image]

So I want to apply these changes and add setup, before I move to vue3. I see that Vue2 already handle with these changes because when I see the components, I dont get any error but I still wanted to ask if I already add setup() and add onMounted inside of it instead of mounted, will it work for vue2?

As an example:

```
setup() {
   onMounted(() => {
     ...
})
}
```

will the example work for Vue2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function like you see have not the same name, this will not throw a error because you just define a function.

But in vue2 if you rewrite your `mounted` by `onMounted`, the function is not understand and doesn't exist in the lifecycle. It will be never called.

Comment: Can I ask additional question about upgrade then? Which changes can I apply in Vue2 before I completely move to Vue3?

Comment: Every project i work started with vue2 is still with it so i'm not really able to respond.
But i think some change will throw a error like the way the app is mounted inside main.js.
You can fund some fondamental change ir https://www.bacancytechnology.com/blog/migrate-from-vue-2-to-vue-3, the way is simple just try a migration on vue3 and see what problem you have.